# React Native: Correct scrolling in horizontal FlatList with Item Separator

Tags: react-native, horizontal-scrolling, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

ReactNative: `v0.52.0`

Platform: `iOS`

My `FlatList` code:

```
<FlatList
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}

  legacyImplementation={false}

  data={this.props.photos}
  renderItem={item => this.renderPhoto(item)}
  keyExtractor={photo => photo.id}

  ItemSeparatorComponent={this.itemSeparatorComponent}
/>
```

Item separator code:

```
itemSeparatorComponent = () => {
    return <View style = {
        {
            height: '100%',
            width: 5,
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        }
    }
    />
}
```

And finally `FlatList` item component:

```
renderPhoto = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <View style = {{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH, height: 'auto' }}>
          <FastImage 
            style = { styles.photo }
            resizeMode = { FastImage.resizeMode.contain }
            source = {{ uri: item.source.uri }}
          /> 
        </View>
    )
}
```

But when scrolling, the `FlatList` makes an offset to the separator but not to the left edge of item:

[image]

And with each new element the `FlatList` adds the width of the all previous separators to offset:

[image]

How to make the `FlatList` component consider the width of the separator component in horizontal scrolling and make proper offset?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same use-case. For anyone looking for a solution, here it is.

Step 1) Don't use `ItemSeparatorComponent` prop. Instead, render it inline in your `renderItem` component.

Step 2) (Key-point). Specify the `width` and `height` in the `style` prop of the `FlatList`. The `width`, in your case, should be `SCREEN_WIDTH + 5`.

Then `Flatlist` will automatically move the entire screen (photo + separator) away when pagination is enabled. So now your code should be like so:-

```
<FlatList
  horizontal
  pagingEnabled={true}
  showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
  legacyImplementation={false}
  data={this.props.photos}
  renderItem={item => this.renderPhoto(item)}
  keyExtractor={photo => photo.id}
  style={{width: SCREEN_WIDTH + 5, height:'100%'}}
/>
```

Render photo code:-

```
renderPhoto = ({ item, index }) => {
return (
    <View style = {{ width: SCREEN_WIDTH + 5, height: 'auto', 
      flexDirection:'row'}}>
      <FastImage 
        style = { styles.photo }
        resizeMode = { FastImage.resizeMode.contain }
        source = {{ uri: item.source.uri }}
      /> 
      {this. itemSeparatorComponent()}
    </View>
)}
```

Item separator code:

```
itemSeparatorComponent = () => {
return <View style = {
    {
        height: '100%',
        width: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
}
/>
}
```

If you still can't figure it out, then look at this component:
https://github.com/zachgibson/react-native-parallax-swiper

Try to go into the implementation, you will see that this guy has provided width and height to the `Animated.ScrollView`.
https://github.com/zachgibson/react-native-parallax-swiper/blob/master/src/ParallaxSwiper.js
Line number: 93 - 97

Answer (score 2):

The top-level view you're returning in the `renderPhoto` function has a width of `SCREEN_WIDTH`, yet the `ItemSeparatorComponent`, which [renders in between each item](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#itemseparatorcomponent), is taking up a width of 5 as per your style definition. Consequently, for each additional item you scroll to, that initial offset will become 5 more pixels on the left.

To fix this, you can either remove the `ItemSeparatorComponent` completely, (as you already have `pagingEnabled` set to true), or set the width of the top-level view returned in `renderPhoto` equal to `SCREEN_WIDTH - 2.5`. That way you'll see half of the item separator on the right edge of one photo and the other half on the left edge of the next photo.

Actually, one other possible solution could be to remove the item separator, set the `renderPhoto` `View`'s width to `SCREEN_WIDTH + 5`, and then include these additional properties inside the style: `{paddingRight: 5, borderRightWidth: 5, borderRightColor: 'red'}`. That way the red separator won't be visible until scrolling left and right, because of the `pagingEnabled` property.